# VBA changes date format when a CSV file saved as XLSX

Tags: vba, excel

I have a csv file which has column D with dates entered and formatted under the australian date format. The rest of data is integers:

```
4/10/2016 (correctly representing 4 Oct 16)
15/03/2017 (correctly representing 15 Mar 17)
```

When I save this file *manually* as xlsx it correctly saves the dates so when I reopen the xlsx file the dates appear correctly:

```
value = 4/10/2016, format = 4/10/2016 (as dd/mm/yyyy)
value = 15/03/2017, format = 15/03/2017 (as dd/mm/yyyy)
```

However, when I do the same thing programmatically:

```
fileNameXLSX = "H:\20160930.xlsb"
fileNameCSV = "H:\20160930.csv"
Set srcBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(filenameCSV, ReadOnly:=True)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
srcBook.SaveAs filename:=fileNameXLSX, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
srcBook.Close False
Set srcBook = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

and open the file, some entries, months/dates get swapped and in that xlsx file those values will become:

```
value = 10/4/2016, format = 10/4/2016 (still dd/mm/yyyy)
value = 15/03/2017, format = 15/03/2017
```

I'm in the australian windows locale. How can I fix this so my VBA code does what I expect it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try setting `local` to true, this should keep the date in the desired format.  In your code this would look like this:

```
fileNameXLSX = "H:\20160930.xlsb"
fileNameCSV = "H:\20160930.csv"
Set srcBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(filenameCSV, ReadOnly:=True)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
srcBook.SaveAs filename:=fileNameXLSX, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
srcBook.Close False
Set srcBook = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx

Comment: Magic. A variant by @Docmarti works as well. Thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to set the Local parameter to True in the Open command if the dates in the csv are not American.

```
fileNameXLSB = "H:\20160930.xlsb"
fileNameCSV = "H:\20160930.csv"
Set srcBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(filenameCSV, ReadOnly:=True, local:=True)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
srcBook.SaveAs Filename:=fileNameXLSB, FileFormat:=xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False
srcBook.Close False
Set srcBook = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: For anyone reading this question - this is the solution to your problem (not the one above). Docmarti is absolutely right that the srcBook requires "local:=True".

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend as a simple solution to add a line of code that selects the column with the dates in it and sets their number format to the convention you prefer- this would look something like this:

```
fileNameXLSX = "H:\20160930.xlsb"
filenameCSV = "H:\20160930.csv"
Set srcBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(filenameCSV, ReadOnly:=True)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
srcBook.SaveAs Filename:=fileNameXLSX, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

srcBook.Sheets(1).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy"

srcBook.Close False
Set srcBook = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, it was the 2nd option to fix for me, local = True must be set when opening the file, not when saving it

(Sorry can't add comments yet)